# What is the probability that $n$ persons have birthdays all within one half year?

Tags: probability, birthday

I'm wondering what the probability is that $n$ persons have birthdays all within 1/2 year.
For instance, two persons always have birthdays within 1/2 year, as the maximal distance between two days is at most 1/2 year.
I suspect this problem to be related to the broken stick problem, which [predicts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274049/a-broken-stick-with-n-breaks) the probablity of $n-1$ points to all lie on 1/2 of a circle to be
$$
\mathbb P = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}
$$
For my example above, $n-1=2$ gives $\mathbb P=\frac{3}{4}$, so, clearly, I misunderstand something here.

Comment: I think the answer to the linked question deals with $n$ points (not $n-1$).

Comment: The part about "$n-1$ points" in the accepted answer is a step that is taken to transform an answer about $n$ points on a ring to one about $n-1$ points on a straight stick. But you are asking about a ring (because you don't consider December to be more than half a year from January), so you should ignore the part of the answer that talks about straight sticks. You just want the part that talks about $n$ points on a ring. So $3$ points leads to probability $\frac34$, but $2$ points leads to probability $1$.